# how to set shipping days for each country magento 2

Tags: shipping

How does the logistics delivery time of the magento 2 website be set to change with the country/region?
For example, when the user chooses the United States, the standard express (free) logistics time is chosen to be 7 - 12 days. If choose the UK, the standard express (free) logistics time varies change from 7 to 20 days.
At the same time, in addition to the standard express (free) mode of transport, add one more DHL delivery method, DHL shipping costs need to pay separately $ 9.99. And DHL's delivery time also changes with country/region.
I want to know is the magento 2 backend have this feature? 
If not, is there a corresponding plugin?
Like this casetify.com below:

[image]